# Any recommendations for online radios for beginners?

Tags: ressources

I listen to french podcasts while driving and it helps me a lot but when I am not driving like when I am at work I'd rather listen to radio, any online French radios that is a mix of music and talk and is rather suitable for beginners? needless to say having a mix of English and French would also be nice.

Comment: We have been debatting on the [meta site](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/127/are-resources-for-learning-french-on-topic-les-demandes-de-ressources-pour-lapp) whether questions about learning resources should be accepted or not on this site. I'm not sure we've reached a consensus yet, so please feel free to (re)visit this discussion and bring your voice!

Comment: Have we had a question about this particular resource yet?  I think we should at least allow one question for each 'kind' of resource, so one for books, one for TV shows, one for podcasts, etc. so we can provide a nice set of reference questions/answers to point people to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est difficile mais je propose [France Inter](http://www.franceinter.fr/) qui propose différentes émissions en français. Dans un registre plus léger, il y a [Rire et Chansons](http://www.rireetchansons.fr/) qui propose des extraits de spectacle d'humoriste en français.

Je ne connais malheureusement pas de radio qui propose un mélange d'anglais et de français (à mon grand désespoir)

Answer (score 3):

Il y a aussi [RFI](http://www.rfi.fr) (Radio France Internationale) qui offre des podcasts en français « simple ».

There's also [RFI](http://www.rfi.fr) (Radio France Internationale) which offers podcasts in "simple" French.